# Android Flip Template

Tags: android, flip, flipview

I am writing an Android app that resembles the flipping template of the app Flipboard. I am not allowed to use any public libraries.

I have written up to having a TextView that changes text when swiping in my app but I can't get around to animating the flipping animations.

- Do I split my canvas into two? Then scale them separately?
- Do I scale the layout instead?
- Do I take a screenshot and then pasting it as a bitmap, then only scaling it? (Not sure if possible)

I really have no idea how I'm going to do this. Any help would be much appreciated.